# Downloading remote / Uploading locale repository and removing any obsolete files

Tags: git

I'm trying to use git as a way keeping my source code up-to-date when working between different computers (I originally used Dropbox, but this became unmanageable).

From my understanding, when you use the command `git pull` it will fetch any changes from the remote repository and merge the changes with any existing files in your local repository.  However, if I have redundant/obsolete files in my local repository, it will not remove them automatically.  Likewise, if I remove a file from my local repository and push the changes to the server, the server will not remove that deleted file.

How to I solve this problem?  What are the necessary commands?

Thanks!

Comment: "the server will not remove that deleted file"? Uhm, isn't your remote a bare repository?

Comment: Bare as in nothing was there previously?  Only until the initial push.  After I've been using it for a while old files still there.

Comment: No, "bare" as in "does not have a working tree". Like what github and the like use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way perform `git pull` and then perform `git reset --hard` which will forcibly reset the working directory to match the remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git clean` to remove those files. See man-page for options (or do `git help clean`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bare to communicate between different repositories. Pulling from non bare is all right, but *pushing* to such repos can be a royal PITA -- well, no, it *is* a royal PITA: for one, you cannot push to a checked out branch by default.

To create a bare, choose a directory in which to put it and do:

```
git init --bare /path/to/repo
```

Then, on all your repositories, add this remote, let's call it `bare`:

```
git remote add bare user@machine:/path/to/repo
```

Choose a reference repository of yours, push the master branch to it:

```
git push bare master
```

Then push all your repository in it, under a dedicated branch, or even namespace. For instance, for repository on machine `host1`:

```
git push bare master host1/master
```

Similarly for `host2`, etc. Choose the naming convention which suits you. Rinse, repeat for all hosts and branches -- and even tags if you have them.

And then push to/pull from as appropriate.

For a more long-term solution, I suggest you use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) if it is packaged for your distribution, or that you install it and configure it: it is git with access privileges on steroids, you can really do a LOT with it.