# git: uploading changes to cloned remote repository

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

I am new to Git, coming from SubVersion.

I have a **main development desktop computer** where my Android app is stored with eclipse's E-GIT. I am currently working away from it, working from my laptop, so I configured **E-Git via SSH**.

- I'm using **eclipse-egit in both places**, so never really dealt with command-line git and its thousand options.
- The clone process was automatically done by eclipse's "**import git project**" without problems, after setting up ssh keys, etc..

Now I've been doing a lot of work (like 300 commits) in my cloned git (the laptop) and will return to my office to resume work in my Main server. and I have a couple questions:

- 1 Everytime I press "Team>Commit" in my laptop, are the commits uploaded to my main desktop git? -it's online 24x7, e-git ssh configured, etc-
- 2 I suppose the answer to 1- is **no**. Do I have to press **"Team>Push to UpStream"** to do it? Or what option would do that?

I've been reading an answer here [Downloading remote / Uploading locale repository and removing any obsolete files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577558/downloading-remote-uploading-locale-repository-and-removing-any-obsolete-files) that suggests creating kind of a bare intermediate repository, but don't understand very well if this applies to my case, because they talk about branches and other stuff while I don't have any, just one normal repo with a master branch that was cloned in my laptop.

I am a little scared because it's the first time I'm doing this, been 2 months out of office, and don't want to risk losing thousands of changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than uploading your commits from your laptop, you could download them from your main computer.

Said differently: just add on your main computer, the repo on your laptop as a remote. Then, just pull from it.

I don't know E-git, but I guess it shouldn't be much different from what you did to clone on your laptop. From the command line it would just looks like

```
git remote add myLaptop ssh me@laptop:/path/to/repo
git pull myLaptop master
```

---

Edit to answer the comment:

You'll add a remote to your existing repo. Hence you won't create a new one.

To get a better understanding of remotes, you might want to read http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html and http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

---

Edit to answer the other comment:

If you have conflicts and if you're sure you don't care about the files on your main computer, you could run, from your main computer:

```
#Discard your un-commited local changes, to avoid git complaining about conflicts
#*Beware* you won't discard changes you're actually interested in!
git reset --hard

#Retrieve the commit from the laptop
git fetch myLaptop

#Checkout the master branch of your laptop
git checkout myLaptop/master

#Move your master on this commit
#*Beware* if your laptop master and main computer master branches diverged, you may lose commits
git checkout -B master
```

Comment: thanks! late accept, I didn't realized the edit, now all makes sense!

Comment: I did as you instructed. The first time it worked OK, but I continued working on the laptop. The next time -i re-issued the command thinking it would just fetch the changed files- git complained about conflicts in most updated files -"merge failed, local modified, remote modified"- . I am sure I only modified the laptop files but anyways, is there a way to tell git to pull from the laptop and and assume the final files are the laptop ones? I mean instead of merge just use the files as they come?

Comment: You can push to repos with working trees, you just can't push to the currently-checked-out branch.  Making paralleled clones and pushing work among them can be very useful.

Comment: Just tested, and you're right! Thanks for this info, I learnt something! I just edited my answer to remove the wrong statement. Please feel free to add another answer presenting a solution using `push` if you will